# How to check if browser is OSX Snow Leopard Safari 5.0

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, osx-snow-leopard

I was wondering if there's a way on how to check if a user is running OSX Snow Leopard Safari 5.0 or 4.0?

I am using PHP, but if there's a javascript or jquery way, also better.

Thanks!

Comment: you should not care, websites should be browser agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.virtualsecrets.com/misc_imgs/javascript/jsBrowsersDetect-demo.html

There's also a lot of other tutorials out there.